# Unoriented graph colouring problem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an unoriented graph with $|V|=17$. We colour the edges of the graph with three separate colours (blue, red, yellow). Prove that any colouring of the graph, there exists a vertex trio in which all the edges have the same colour.

Comment: You mean, I assume a complete graph?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the same when $G$ is a complete graph with $6$ vertices, and the edges are coloured with only two colours, blue and red?

Comment: @CompulsiveMathurbator Yes, a complete graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider any arbitrary vertex A of the graph. Then it is connected to 16 other vertices by 16 other edges, which by the pigeon hole principle has at least 6 edges of the same colour for some colour, say blue.

**Case 1:** If any two of these vertices are connected by a blue edge, that is the desired triangle.

**Case 2:** Else pick another vertex B such that B is connected to A by a blue edge. Now B is connected to five other vertices that are connected to A by a blue edge, none of which are connected to each other by a blue edge. By the pigeon hole principle again, at least 3 of them are connected to B by one of the two remaining colours, say red. Then

**Sub-Case 1:** At least two of the three are connected to each other by a red edge, then B and those two form the desired trio

**Sub-Case 2:** No pair of the three are connected by a red edge. Then those three are completely connected and are not connected by a blue or red edge. Thus they form a yellow triangle, and are the desired trio.